# Wrong scaffolding window in empty project ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC6 project created using the WebAPI project template. I noticed Add > Controller was missing so I added the package Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc. This gave me the option, however, I don't get the same window on this project as I do on a project started with the Web Application project template.

My project (WebAPI):
[image]

The window I am trying to get - "Add Scaffolding" (project started with Web Application project template):

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have Entity Framework

Comment: I do have Entity Framework.

Comment: This feature will be supported in the future releases of ASP.NET.

Comment: It's already supported, it just shows up inconsistently!